# AngularJS: How to get directive's name in the linking function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to use directive's name inside the linking function. How could I get it?

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // How could I get directive's name here (i.e. 'myDirective')?
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: why would you wanna do that, if i may ask?

Comment: I thought to possibly use directive's name as a prefix to something. But, generally, I'm just curious to know how difficult it is.

Comment: i think it would be quite difficult - you'd have to know at least the order of the injector invocation, and than you can [look up the module's `_invokeQueue`](http://plnkr.co/edit/isJK8bwMRp7CERjfLakR?p=preview) (which should be internal) for the directive's injection - this of course will be *extremely rigid*, so i don't recommend it.

Comment: angular offers its own dependency injection, so most of the time you will actually be looking things up by their name, referring to the DIC (e.g. `$injector.get('myDirective')`). getting the name from it would not be so easy. but i hope i'm mistaken - such an option could be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply define it outside the injection:

```js
var name = 'myDirective';
app.directive(name, function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(name); // --> myDirective
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 10):

It is possible inside [`compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) function of **directive**.

```
directives.directive('myNamedDir', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        compile: function(cElem, cAttrs, transclude) {
            var name = this.name;
            return function linkFunction(){
                //use name
            }
        }
   }]);
```

Comment: It is also possible in `link`, `template`, pre-linking... functions.

Answer (score -1):

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(arguments.callee.directiveName); // --> myDirective
        }
    };
});
```

the `arguments.callee.caller` property deprecated in JavaScript